# Why does $\sum \frac{1}{n^{(1+ 1/n)}}$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why does the following series diverge?

$$\sum \frac{1}{n^{(1 + 1/n)}}=1+\frac{1}{2^{1 + 1/2}}+\frac{1}{3^{1 + 1/3}}+\cdots$$

The hint is to use comparison test but I do not see obvious choice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$, so you can use the limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: More explicitly, $n^{1/n}=e^{\frac{\ln n}n}$, and the limit of the exponent an be computed using, say, L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo you mean using $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n} = \lim_{a \to \infty}\frac{\ln 2^a}{2^a} = 0$

Comment: @user1952009 that is a nice way of putting it

Answer (score 0):

The integral test also works. It is not difficult to see that, when $x\geq1
 $, $x^{-1/x}
 $ has a minimum at $x=e
 $. So$$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}\ge\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{1+1/x}}\geq\frac{1}{e^{1/e}}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx=\infty.$$